# Show that n! is equal to the recursive derangement.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Prove that An=n!, the number of permutations of n elements, and Dn, the number of permutations of n elements without fixed points, satisfy the recursive equation:
Dn = (n−1)(Dn−1 + Dn−2).

I've gotten to prove that Dn satifies such recurrence. I need help showing that n! satifies it.

Comment: It's as simple as noting

$$A_n = nA_{n-1} - A_{n-1} + (n-1)A_{n-2}$$

and then noting $A_k = k!$ for all $k$ sufficiently large (given), and using the property of factorials where $k(k-1)! = k!$

Comment: Use $(n-1)!/n!=1/n$ and $(n-2)!/n!=1/[(n-1)n]$.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Two induction proofs of the formula $D_n = (n - 1)(D_{n - 1} + D_{n - 2})$ are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1679426/prove-by-induction-that-the-number-of-derangements-of-length-n-is-d-n-n-1).  If you are asking how $A_n$ is related to $D_n$, note that any permutation has zero fixed points or one fixed point or two fixed points or ... or $n$ fixed points.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.